# SSMS configuration

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I recently downloaded SQL Server 2019 and I was using 2017 version before. After I installed it, SSMS is still using the 2017 version can someone tell me how do I get it to use the 2019 version? Knowing that I have uninstalled 2017 version

Comment: You can only ever have **one** unnamed default instance on your computer. So if you had SQL Server 2017 installed, most likely, the installation of SQL Server 2019 required you to choose a custom **instance name**  which you now need to use in connecting to it. So instead of `.` or `(local)` or `localhost` for your default, unnamed instance - just use `.\INSTANCE` or `(local)\INSTANCE` instead - and replace `INSTANCE` with whatever actual instance name you choose when installing SQL Server 2019 ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IF you are connecting with the correct instances that is 2019 and still you are getting the 2017 version in that case you need to check the compatibility level for 2019 it should be 150. Go to DB property -> Option -> Check compatibility level here

[compatibility level Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2vY97.png)